# importing JSON object - Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have  a JSON object as following:

```
details = {

        "name"      : "ram",
        "place"     : "abc",
        "height"    : 5.10,
        "list"      : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        "tuple"     : (0,1,2),
        "colors"    : {"mng":"white","aft" : "blue","night":"red"},
        "car"       : "None",
        "bike"      : "True",

        }
```

while i'm converting above json object in python, I have imported json module , and verified all methods as below.

```
import json
print (dir(python))
```

Now I can see  **'dump', 'dumps', 'encoder', 'load', 'loads',** 'scanner' methods, But when  I encode above json object like below

```
a = json.dump(details)
print (s)
```

I m geeting Attribute  error as

> AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'dump'

In addition to above I would like to know what will be the best way to import json objects in python code (other than import json)

using python 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anything (a python file or a folder) in your current directory named `json` or `json.py`? That may just be what you are importing, rather than the actual `json` module.

Comment: [`dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) needs a "`.write()`-supporting file-like object" as the second argument. If you want to serialise the the object into a string, use [`dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).